# How are connections accessed with the 2007 Facebook PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

so with the new graph API i can access a user's statuses with something straightforward like:

```
$facebook->api('/me/statuses');
```

However, I am currently **stuck** with the older Facebook PHP library (~2007, copyright 2004-2009). Will switch later but for now need to make this work with the old library.

Question: How do I do the same thing (get a user's statuses, or other allowed connections) given a facebook object has been defined like:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(API_KEY, SECRET);
```

I don't see any references to the old documentation that could help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my own answer. Doing the same thing with the old REST API is simple with:

```
$facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($fb_id, 'status')
```

Now need to figure out Brent Baisley's suggestion about having two instances running at the same time...that would be pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use both the new version and the old version? You will probably need to edit one of the versions and change the name of the class in the file so there are no conflicts when including the files. But you should be able to create 2 instances, one with the new version and one with the old.

But regardless, both versions in the end to a curl request. You can search the code for curl_exec to find the 1 function that everything eventually funnels through. This is true in both the older and new versions.

Comment: This is interesting...but how about cookies? Do they get passed to both instances if I'm only calling one instance upon sign in (old api) and then later..one to access user connections (new api)

Comment: Cookies are passed to the server, not code. Any and all code can read and use them at any time.

Comment: I don't think this works...not able to authenticate two different facebook instances...changed the class name of the newer version so its not that...

Comment: Can you create instances of either one independently? Are you getting errors on whichever comes second? I assume you are using different variable names for each instance.